# Is there any table where Oracle APEX usage log is stored

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I was just wondering if there is any standard table , where we can see which user has accessed which report in Oracle APEX, based on date and time. Basically the audit history ?

I can do it by inserting the needed data in a custom table but, is there any standard way, where we have all this information?

Regards,

Abha

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oracle APEX has indeed internal tables where it stores all of this information. The name of the view to have insight into this data is **apex_workspace_activity_log.**

```
select s.workspace,
       s.apex_user,
       s.application_id,
       s.application_name,
       s.page_id,
       s.page_name,
       s.view_date,
       s.apex_session_id
from   apex_workspace_activity_log s
/
```

Here you can see WHO accessed a page, WHAT page has been accessed and WHEN that page has been accessed (date and time). This is not on individual report level, as you asked for, but at least you can see it on page level.

Use following views to see what report exists on which page and join that information as you like.

```
apex_application_page_rpt
apex_application_page_ir
apex_appl_page_igs
```

Comment: An incredibly useful table. More detail here http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2018/10/odc-appreciation-day-apex-workspace-activity-log.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Gilliam and Scott...That's exactly what I was looking for !

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from APEX_WORKSPACE_ACTIVITY_LOG

select * from APEX_ACTIVITY_LOG
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from APEX_DEBUG_MESSAGES

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).